# Как не перезапуская бота обновить файлы модулей

Tags: javascript, node.js, бот, fs

У меня есть бот (программа на node.js). Есть главный файл, в который я подгружаю модули. Перезагрузка занимает много времени (и я это делаю постоянно). Как после **изменения** какого-то модуля не перезагружать всего бота, чтобы он с этим **изменённым** модулем работал.

***Я пытался (fs.readdir) новый модуль, каждый раз, когда он вызывался, но главный файл всё время работал со старой версией до перезагрузки.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53105303/4496422

Comment: nörbörnën, спасибо